# JavaScript toggle button not changing button state

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that when clicked, I would like the text to change from **ON** to **OFF** (toggle). However, I cannot seem to get the JavaScript to do this. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<script src="testButton.js"></script>
<style>
    button {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="toggle">Turn on</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#toggle').on('click', function(e){
        let status;
        if($(this).text() == 'Turn on') {
            $(this).text('Turn off')
            status = 'on';
        } else {
            $(this).text('Turn off');
            status = 'off';
        }
        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a few changes.
I took your idea with comparing the text of the element this is my solution**1**. But I would recommend using a boolean variable , I have seen that you have this variable **status**. You can use this as the toggle **2**.

**1.)** In one I compare the status variable if it is true then I set the text to "turn off" and set the status to false; When the status variable is false then I set the text to "turn on" and set the status to true.

**2.)** In two I just compare the text of the element when it is "Turn On" then I set the text to "Turn Off" and backwards.

Here is the first example. **1.)**
This here is a better solution with a boolean variable

```js
let status = true;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#toggle').on('click', function(e){
       
        if(status === true) {
            $(this).text('Turn off')
            status = false;
            
        } else if(status === false) {
            
            $(this).text('Turn on')
            status = true;
            
        }
        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<script src="testButton.js"></script>
<style>
    button {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="toggle">Turn on</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Comparing the text 2.)**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#toggle').on('click', function(e){
       
        if($(this).text() === 'Turn on') {
            $(this).text('Turn off')
            
        } else {
            $(this).text() === 'Turn off';
            $(this).text('Turn on')
            
        }
        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<script src="testButton.js"></script>
<style>
    button {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        <button id="toggle">Turn on</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks. I forgot to add the jQuery reference as well

Comment: Ahja :D I also changed the else to else if for a check maybe it s easier to understand and you can add an else part for Invalid arguments maybe if something weird happens to catch this like `else{throw new Error("Something Weird Happened"}`